# Using a C++11 initializer_list with a recursively defined type using constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, recursive-datastructures, constexpr

Is it possible to use the C++11 `initializer_list` to assemble a recursively defined class such as `Foo`, below, using `constexpr` constructors:

```
template <size_t N>
struct Foo {
  constexpr Foo(int x, Foo<N-1> f) : x(x), xs(xs) {}
  int x;
  Foo<N-1> xs;
};

template <> struct Foo<0> {};
```

I can initialise a `Foo<3>` using:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Foo<3> a = Foo<3>(1,Foo<2>(2,Foo<1>(3,Foo<0>())));
  return 0;
}
```

It would be nice to use Foo<3> a = {1,2,3} instead. If there was a `constexpr tail` function in `initializer_list` I think it should work.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to write a constructor using an `initializer_list` for that class.  Unrelated: the class would be smaller if you specialized `Foo<1>` instead of zero.

Comment: Why would the class template be smaller?

Comment: Except for special cases (of which yours does not qualify) all classes are at least 1 byte.  So all `Foo` will always have a byte that is the `Foo<0>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, in a kind of round-about way, effectively unpacking and repacking the initializer list to a more suited format. However, there is a better (imho) way: Variadic templates.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <iostream>

template <size_t N>
struct Foo {
  template<class... Tail>
  constexpr Foo(int i, Tail... t) : x(i), xs(t...) {}

  void print(){
    std::cout << "(" << x << ", ";
    xs.print();
    std::cout << ")";
  }

  int x;
  Foo<N-1> xs;
};

template <> 
struct Foo<1> {
  constexpr Foo(int i) : x(i) {}
  void print(){ std::cout << "(" << x << ")"; }
  int x;
};

int main(){
 Foo<3> x = {1, 2, 3};
 x.print();
 std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Output as expected:

> (1, (2, (3)))

Note that I chose `1` as the base case, as it simply makes more sense.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely the better way to go. +1

Comment: Aha, I thought you had to use `initialization_list`. This looks good.

Comment: @user: One of the goals behind the uniform initialization syntax was to be able to instantiate any class, no matter the constructor (or lack thereof). `initializer_list` constructors are preferred if present, but if not, the compiler just tries to match a constructor with the list of values. And this just reminds me that the initialization could be written as `Foo<3> x(1, 2, 3);` aswell. Oh well...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a compiler that could compile it, but I think the correct answer is something along the lines of:

```
template <size_t N>
struct Foo {
  constexpr Foo(int x, Foo<N-1> f)   //template iterator constructor
  : x(x), xs(xs) {}
  Foo(std::initializer_list<int> f)  //initializer list constructor
  : x(*f.begin()), xs(++f.begin(), f.end()) 
  { static_assert(xs.size()==N, "incorrect number of values in initializer list");}
  template<class iter>
  Foo(iter first, iter last)  //template iterator constructor
  : x(*first), xs(++first, last) {}  //UB if wrong number of values given

  int x;
  Foo<N-1> xs;
};

template <> 
struct Foo<1> { //I use 1 for smaller structures
  constexpr Foo(int f) 
  : x(f) {}
  Foo(std::initializer_list<int> f) 
  : x(*f.begin())
  { static_assert(xs.size()==1, "incorrect number of values in initializer list");}
  template<class iter>
  Foo(iter first, iter last)
  : x(*first)
  { assert(first+1 == last); } 

  int x;
};
```

For a recursive structure, the initializer list would have to pass to a constructor that takes iterators, recursively.

Comment: Note that this has UB behavior all over, beacuse I haven't worked out exactly how to use initializer_lists, but this is roughly the concept.  Xeo said he knew ways to "fix" my code, which would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make a function called

```
template<class T>
constexpr T initlist_val(initializer_list<T>& list, int index) {
  return (index < list.size()) ? *(list.begin() + index) : 0;
}
```

Now you can go

```
class MyClass {
public:
  int A, int B;
  constexpr MyClass(const initializer_list<int>& list) : A(initlist_val(list,0)), B(initlist_val(1)) {
  // Put nothing here etc..
  }

};
```

You do not need all the other stuff. This can work with GCC not tested with anything else. Probably is not correct in terms of the rules.

Comment: how is this answer the question?

Comment: `Probably is not correct in terms of the rules.` Don't post it, then! It's certainly "incorrect" in terms of (A) being irrelevant to the Q; (B) not understanding uniform initialisation & so pointlessly reinventing the wheel by shoehorning `std::initializer_list` into the role of memberwise initialisation, for which normal *braced init-list*s already suffice; (C) inviting UB by not `assert`ing on the number of elements; (D) assuming `T` is always convertible to `0`; (E) passing by reference despite `initializer_list` being a small pair of pointers & the stdlib passing by value, etc. Poor effort